# Posting multiple JSON files at onece

Tags: json, google-apps-script, request

I am working with an api (Track-pod) and uploading JSON files to their server using a google apps script. I know this question has probably already been answered, but I have searched google extensively and couldn't find an answer, or maybe I just wasn't typing in the right keywords. Each Json file that I am uploading contains information on customers for the company I am working for. The way I am doing it is like so

```
 for each(var item in array)
  {
   option.payload = JSON.stringify(item); 
   UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, option);
  }
```

In my code the array is an array of objects for each customer. I was wondering if I have to constantly make requests, or is there a way to upload all the JSON files at once. Or at least make it faster.

Answer (score 2):

To save some time you can use UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(). It will take an array of request as parameter and you can do up to 10 requests at the same time if I well remember.

Don't forget to check destination endpoint limit to not over charge it.

Reference : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchAll(Object)

Stéphane